# Best Practice - Where to declare variables in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Generally in procedural/imperative languages, it's best practice to place variable declarations as close to usage as possible.

This seems a little hazy in lisp, considering more code is used if there are separate `lets`.

Given an example function using two `lets`:

```
(defun draw-box (new-image corners)
  (let ((h-len (- (alast (alast corners))
                  (alast (car corners))))
        (h-offset (alast (car corners))))
    (dotimes (i h-len)
      (setf (aref new-image (car (car corners)) (+ i h-offset) 0) 0)
      (setf (aref new-image (car (car corners)) (+ i h-offset) 1) 255)
      (setf (aref new-image (car (car corners)) (+ i h-offset) 2) 0)

      (setf (aref new-image (car (alast corners)) (+ i h-offset) 0) 0)
      (setf (aref new-image (car (alast corners)) (+ i h-offset) 1) 255)
      (setf (aref new-image (car (alast corners)) (+ i h-offset) 2) 0)))

  (let ((v-len (- (car (alast corners))
                  (car (car corners))))
        (v-offset (car (car corners))))
    (dotimes (i v-len)
      (setf (aref new-image (+ i v-offset) (alast (car corners)) 0) 0)
      (setf (aref new-image (+ i v-offset) (alast (car corners)) 1) 255)
      (setf (aref new-image (+ i v-offset) (alast (car corners)) 2) 0)

      (setf (aref new-image (+ i v-offset) (alast (alast corners)) 0) 0)
      (setf (aref new-image (+ i v-offset) (alast (alast corners)) 1) 255)
      (setf (aref new-image (+ i v-offset) (alast (alast corners)) 2) 0))))
```

Where I'm not going to use `v-len` and `v-offset` until halfway down the function, I'm hesitant to declare it at the top of the function just to use only a single `let`.

What is generally regarded as best practice when declaring variables in longer functions where one might only use a variable later on in the function?

Comment: Interesting question, but topics about how to write code should rather go to stackoverflow

Comment: I did initially start writing the question up on SO, but was warned that "best practice" questions would be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Ok ! Difficult to follow the sometimes contradictory editorial approches here and there....

Comment: "Generally in procedural/imperative languages, it's best practice to place variable declarations as close to usage as possible.": This is not always the case: in Pascal you have to declare variables before the beginning of a block. If I remember correctly, `C` has the same rule, unless this has been changed in recent revisions of the language. I think the rationale behind this approach is that a block should never be too long anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is correct: we *bind* (rather than *declare*, as in other languages) variables exactly where we need them. (In your case, however, you *are* using `h-offset` in the 1st half of your function, just without *naming* it).

The rationale is the same - code readability.

Note that you do not need to bind a single use variable, you can just write

```
(dotimes (i (- (alast ...) (alast ...)))
  ...)
```

Note also that you might want to make a few other changes (e.g., single call to `setf` and defining a separate function that modifies `image`).

Note also that you should not recompute things like `(alast (alast corners))` in a loop (I surmise from the name that each `alast` has linear speed), so you should probably do something like this:

```
(defun draw-box (new-image corners)
  (let* ((corners-0 (car corners))
         (v-offset (car corners-0))
         (h-offset (alast corners-0))
         (corners-l (alast corners))
         (h-last (alast corners-l))
         (v-last (car corners-l)))
    (flet ((set-0-255-0 (x y)
             (setf (aref new-image x y 0) 0
                   (aref new-image x y 1) 255
                   (aref new-image x y 2) 0)))
      (loop for i = h-offset below h-last do
          (set-0-255-0 v-offset i)
          (set-0-255-0 v-last i))
      (loop for i = v-offset below v-last do
          (set-0-255-0 i h-offset)
          (set-0-255-0 i h-last)))))
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.
With single-use functions like `set-0-255-0` (assuming I only use it in that one function) would it be better to `flet` it inside `draw-box`?

Comment: Yes, if you are sure you will never need it, `flet` is quite appropriate.

Comment: it might also be helpful to declare the function to be inlined...

Comment: in the example it's probably 255 and not 2? Not that it matters much for the example...